# MySQL: fetching a null or an empty string

Tags: mysql

I know whats the difference between a `NULL` value and an empty string (`""`) value, but if I want to get a value by using the `OR` keyword, I get no result for a `NULL` value

The table i want to query looks like this:

```
 titles_and_tags
+----+----------+------+
| id | title    | tag  |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | title1   | NULL |
|  2 | title2   | tag1 |
|  3 | title3   | tag2 |
|  4 | edit     | NULL |
|  5 | rowdata  | div  |
+----+----------+------+
```

The query i use looks like this:

```
select * 
  from `titles_and_tags` 
 WHERE `title` LIKE "title%" 
   AND `tag` = "tag1" OR `tag` IS NULL
```

So i want to get here a rows (id: 1,2), BUT this results 0 rows. What have i done wrong?

**EDIT**

Sorry, i forgot thats my main problem is this:

```
select * 
  from `titles_and_tags` 
WHERE `title` LIKE "title%" 
AND `tag` = "tag1" OR `tag` LIKE '%'
```

So this more like an off-topic, sorry

Comment: I tried same thing and it does return zero rows. Why?

Comment: even 
`Select * 
  from `titles_and_tags` 
 WHERE  `tag` IS NULL` will return zero i think

Comment: @Taz: Not for me. Are you sure that you are executing the query correctly? Does `SELECT * FROM titles_and_tags` return any rows?

Comment: I must be something wrong then. SELECT * FROM titles_and_tags returns all rows.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
select 
  * 
from 
  `titles_and_tags`
WHERE 
  `title` LIKE "title%" AND 
  (`tag` = "tag1" OR `tag` IS NULL)
```

You left the wildcard `%` off your `like`, plus you should enclose in parenthesis the `or` clause for clarity and to explicitly group the logic together to make sure it is executed in the way that you intended.

**EDIT:**
In your edit `tag like '%'` will match all rows in which tag is not `null`.  *Any* comparison other than `is` or `not is` with a `null` value is false.  I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the last query, but I suspect the one that you asked the question with originally is more like what you actually want.

Comment: OK, the wildcard isn't the problem, it exists, i just forgot to add it here, but thanks for perception :)

Comment: +1 Although the parentheses *do* matter for this query. The example data just doesn't demonstrate a difference. Try inserting a row (4, 'nottitle', NULL) and then compare with and without parentheses.

Comment: Ok, now this represents my current database structure, nearly perfect (except, there are a few more columns :))

Comment: Then you're leaving something else that's important out of the question, for the table and query given this should work.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I've replicated your case and it works, the parenthesis are the most important. Without them, you would get all columns where (`title` LIKE "title%" AND `tag` = "tag1") OR `tag` IS NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments my guess is that you have inserted either the string `'NULL'` or the empty string `''` into the database instead of the special value `NULL`. To confirm this try the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM titles_and_tags
WHERE tag IN ('NULL', '')
```

If this returns any rows, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try (Dont wrap the column name tag in anything. or if you wrap them use backtics instead of single quotes.  as suggested by anthony)

```
select * 
  from `titles_and_tags` 
 WHERE title LIKE "title%" 
   AND (tag = "tag1" OR tag IS NULL)
```

Comment: you only need backticks for MySQL keywords, and referencing column aliases in the GROUP BY/HAVING clauses.